# iOS - Crash in try block while application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, try-catch

Application launch crash when execution happen in the if condition `[environMent objectForKey:key]`.  How to fix this crash?

**Crash log:**

```
0x2e2cdfe3 CFDictionaryGetValue + 99
0x00505d87 -[Environments getValueforKey:] (Environments.m:62)
```

**Code:**

```
    @try {
         if (environMent != nil) 
         {
                if ((key != nil) && ![key isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [key length] > 0 && [environMent objectForKey:key])
                {
                    // Build the array from the plist
                    value = [environMent objectForKey:key];
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to get the object from plist: %@", [exception reason]);
        }
```

Full Crash Log:http://pastebin.com/LUjPJeAy

Comment: Show the full stack trace and the exception name and message. What is the key and the object when it crashes?

Comment: Full Crash Log:http://pastebin.com/LUjPJeAy

Comment: I guess you've over released something. What is the exception message?

Comment: Exception message not there in the crash log Wain..

Comment: Customer side crash, we don't have device log. We are handling the catch block.

Comment: It should be in the console. Have you not been able to duplicate? Create a release build and test it.

Comment: Sorry... We are tested no of times, but not able to replicate this crash again in my device Wain.. Only crash log we have...

Comment: Please add to you question the code of how you declare and initialize the variable **environMent**.  And just for pure curiosity, why is there a capital **M** in the variable name?

Comment: Defined in implementation class (Singleton class) without any property.   NSDictionary *environMent;

@implementation Environments

Comment: Defined in implementation class (Singleton class) without any property.   NSDictionary *environMent; Full code:http://pastebin.com/kuxhApty Two different thread focusing the same instance in run time(environMen).